# LINQ result is not showing as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, view, foreach

I'm trying to query for a particular column & to show the item list in view properly one after another. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage()
    {
        using (var context = new ImageTrialDBEntities())
        {
            var pathlist = (from s in context.Images 
                           select s.ImageLink).ToList();

            var model = new ImageModel();

            model.ImageList = pathlist;


            return View(model);
        }

    }
```

Model:

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public IList<string> ImageList { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<div>
@foreach (var s in Model.ImageList)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ImageList)
    <br />

}

</div>
```

The list is showing like this:

[image]

I would like to show one at a time with a break in between. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.ImageList)
```

with

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 loops in the view code. Try just printing out the variable s.

Comment: I didn't get it, I tried to remove the foreach loops but it didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, I meant keep the @foreach, but inside it - display s, not the whole ImageList

Comment: Thanks, it took me a little time, but get the clue from your answer.

Comment: To be honest I want to show the image. I have the image stored in a folder & the path in database. I can pass the path to the view but need to use the path as img src! But can not do it till now. Would be great if can help me over that. Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: Make sure the images folder is accessible to IIS, but here is the code: `foreach (var img in Model.Images) { <img src="@img" /> <br /> }`